# PHP preg_replace ( ) error disallowed Unicode code point

Tags: php, regex, unicode

I'm having some trouble using a 3rd party API, which throws the following PHP error

```
preg_replace(): Compilation failed: disallowed Unicode code point (>= 0xd800 && <= 0xdfff) at offset 42  in /.../SoapClient.php on line 20
```

Can some one help me with understating what this regex means,

```
[\x{0}-\x{8}\x{B}-\x{C}\x{E}-\x{1F}\x{D800}-\x{DFFF}]
```

This is the value it tries to match

```
5f42caa3-1f41-4ff3-8b6c-3f79e45ed0f1
```

This is the code bit in the API,

```
$result = preg_replace('/[\x{0}-\x{8}\x{B}-\x{C}\x{E}-\x{1F}\x{D800}-\x{DFFF}]/u', '', $result);
```

**UPDATE:**

By the way I found in the internet making "D"s in the Regex to "E"s will fix the issue, and surpassingly it did fix the issue,

New RegEx,

```
 [\x{0}-\x{8}\x{B}-\x{C}\x{E}-\x{1F}\x{E800}-\x{EFFF}]
```

But I dont know its a real fix or not, so still my question is valid.

Comment: The regex matches a character in the range given, but I don't think it will match what you claim it is trying to match.

Comment: Yep but why it works when I change the Ds Es.. is another thing I dont get... any ideas :(

Comment: It works, because you changed the range of characters to something allowed by the engine. The original range contains [surrogate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_of_Unicode_characters#Surrogates), which is not allowed by PCRE.