# Writing Javascript UTF Regular Expression in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I need to rewrite this javascript regular expression in PHP for use with preg_replace:

```
var PATTERN = /([\ud800-\udbff])([\udc00-\udfff])/g;
```

If I use:

```
$strText = preg_replace("/([\ud800-\udbff])([\udc00-\udfff])/", "emoji", $strText);
```

I get:

> Compilation failed: PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N{name}, \U, or \u at offset 3

Comment: try replacing `\ud800` with `\x{d800}`

Comment: If I use: `preg_replace("/([\x{d800}-\x{dbff}])([\x{dc00}-\x{dfff}])/", "emoji", $strText);` I get `Compilation failed: character value in \x{...} sequence is too large at offset 9.`

Comment: try adding a `u` at the end of your regex. `...)/u"...`

Comment: As an aside, the capture groups are useless and the first range can be replaced with `\p{Cs}`: `~(*UTF8)\p{Cs}[\x{dc00}-\x{dfff}]~`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
preg_replace("/([\x{d800}-\x{dbff}])([\x{dc00}-\x{dfff}])/u", "emoji", $strText);
```

PCRE doesn't support the `\uXXXX` format, so you can use `\x{XXXX}` instead. Also you'll need the `u` modifier (at end of regex) for dealing with UTF-8

---

Information on syntax from http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

> Perl and PCRE do not support the \uFFFF syntax. They use \x{FFFF}
>   instead.

Information on `u` modifier from http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

> u (PCRE_UTF8) This modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE
>   that is incompatible with Perl. Pattern and subject strings are
>   treated as UTF-8. This modifier is available from PHP 4.1.0 or greater
>   on Unix and from PHP 4.2.3 on win32. UTF-8 validity of the pattern and
>   the subject is checked since PHP 4.3.5. An invalid subject will cause
>   the preg_* function to match nothing; an invalid pattern will trigger
>   an error of level E_WARNING. Five and six octet UTF-8 sequences are
>   regarded as invalid since PHP 5.3.4 (resp. PCRE 7.3 2007-08-28);
>   formerly those have been regarded as valid UTF-8.

Comment: I get `Compilation failed: disallowed Unicode code point (>= 0xd800 && <= 0xdfff) at offset 9` with this.

Comment: @OneCleverMonkey, I searched that error and found this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21666895/php-preg-replace-error-disallowed-unicode-code-point, it seems weird, but can you try replacing the **leading** D's with E's?

Comment: Or convert to UTF8 (presumably from UTF16) before doing your regex, http://wisercoder.com/php-preg_match-failing-reason-blame-utf-16/